# ubuntu linux in rackspace cloud but www-data user does not show www-data@server1 for login shell

Tags: shell, ubuntu, rackspace

I got a server running on ubuntu 11.10 on rackspace cloud

root and other users are successfully showing the login shell in the format

root@server1:

however, this is not true for www-data user.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root and other user accounts are set to  /bin/sh

For www-data, you need to change the login shell for this.

login via ssh as root

and type

```
chsh -s /bin/bash www-data
```

This will change the login shell for www-data such that the /bin/sh is used